# How to find 1st maximum element of an array in PL/SQL

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql

Suppose given array is
`1,2,3,4,5,6`

It should give me `6` as an output.

This is incomplete code as I am stuck here.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  TYPE maxarray IS VARRAY(10) OF NUMBER NOT NULL;
  v_element maxarray := maxarray(1,2,3,4,5,6);
  v_max     NUMBER;
BEGIN


END;
```

Comment: There is no built-in method for this. I'd loop through it saving the current highest value in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add a 21c version using the more convenient [`values of` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-3F424C1F-9C0F-4002-859C-DEAD94FECA82):

```
for i in values of myarray loop
    v_max := greatest(v_max,i);
end loop;
```

This assumes `v_max` has been initialised with some non-null value from `myarray`, such as `v_max number := myarray(myarray.first)` or `-binary_float_infinity`.

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through the array and find the maximum.

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE maxarray IS VARRAY(10) OF NUMBER NOT NULL;
  v_element maxarray := maxarray(1,5,4,3,6,2);
  v_max     NUMBER;
  idx       PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  idx := v_element.FIRST;
  LOOP
    EXIT WHEN idx IS NULL;
    IF v_max IS NULL OR v_max < v_element(idx) THEN
      v_max := v_element(idx);
    END IF;
    idx := v_element.NEXT(idx);
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_max);
END;
/
```

The code above will work for `VARRAY`, nested table or an associative array (regardless of whether they are dense or sparse).

If you are just using a dense array then you can use:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE maxarray IS VARRAY(10) OF NUMBER NOT NULL;
  v_element maxarray := maxarray(1,5,4,3,6,2);
  v_max     NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. v_element.COUNT LOOP
    IF v_max IS NULL OR v_max < v_element(i) THEN
      v_max := v_element(i);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_max);
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0000a953233dd93a842b441d8eca9643)*